# Unlist a sublist and combine their elements under the same list

Tags: r, data-manipulation, nested-lists

I have a list of lists problem where I want to just unlist the bottom-level list and then combine all the elements in the same list. Here is the example:

```
alllist <- list(list(5,c(1,2)),list(3,c(4,5))) #A list of two sublists
alllist
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 5

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 4 5

#Unlist will unlist all levels
unlist(alllist, recursive = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 5
#But I want to keep the top level such that the result would be:
[1]
5 1 2

[2]
3 4 5
#I would also like to keep the order of the elements from the sublist while unlisting them
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and `unlist`

```
lapply(alllist, unlist)
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 5 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5
```